# iOS 9 - Customising UITextField to make it tags field (Swift 2)

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm trying to find a way to turn UITextField into something like the following attached image (Another example is StackOverflow tags field).

Is there any native support to do something like this?
If not, but it's possible to do so, can someone tell me where to start?

The whole point of this is to make word editing easier as users type in by turning each word into a tag with a delete icon after a comma or a space.

[image: selectable word]

Comment: user looking for this? https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/antagsview

Answer (score 2):

There is no native support in iOS for this type of thing. You'll need a custom view instead.

Alternatively, just use a third party library. Here's just one I found on Github: https://github.com/ali312/TLTagsControl I'm sure there are a few out there which may work just as well/better for your particular needs.